# grunt : Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman-generator

I have a problem in a grunt project. I was using node.js 8.x and it worked fine.

After I update node.js to 14.x I got this error.

> ```
> Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
> ```

Here is the grunt file :

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

var tasks = { scope: ['devDependencies', 'dependencies'] };
var options = {
    config: { src: "../../base/grunt/*.js" },
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
};
var configs = require('load-grunt-configs')(grunt, options);
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, tasks);
grunt.initConfig(configs);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'copy', 'sass', 'concat', 'cssmin', 'uglify'
]);

grunt.registerTask('deploy', [
    'build',
    'ftp-deploy:uploadToCDN'
]);

grunt.registerTask('watcher', [
    'build',
    'watch'
]);

grunt.registerTask('site-push', ['copy:importLar', 'liferaySiteGenerate:zipLar']);
grunt.registerTask('struct-push', ['copy:importStruct', 'liferayStructureGenerate:deployStructures']);
grunt.registerTask('templates-push', ['copy:importTemplates', 'liferayTemplateGenerate:deployTemplates']);

};
```

Here is the function to copy function :

```js
module.exports = function () {
return {
    importJavascript: {
        src: "node_modules/@axiellarena/**/dist/*.dist.js",
        dest: "src/js/",
        filter: "isFile",
        flatten: true,
        expand: true,
        rename: function (dest, src) {
            let start = src.indexOf('js/');
            let end = src.length;
            return dest + '_arena-' + src.substring(start, end);
        }
    },
    importScss: {
        src: ["node_modules/@axiellarena/**/dist/**/*.scss"],
        dest: "src/styles/arena-import/",
        filter: "isFile",
        flatten: false,
        expand: true,
        rename: function (dest, src) {
            let start = src.indexOf('dist/') + 5;
            let end = src.length;
            return dest + src.substring(start, end);
        }
    },
    exportScss: {
        src: ["src/styles/**/*.scss"],
        dest: "dist/<%= pkg.path %>/",
        flatten: false,
        expand: true,
        rename: function (dest, src) {
            let start = src.indexOf('styles/') + 7;
            let end = src.length;
            return dest + src.substring(start, end);
        }
    },
    exportStruct: {
        src: ["src/resources/*"],
        dest: "dist/struct/<%= pkg.path %>",
        flatten: true,
        expand: true
    },
    exportTemplate: {
        src: ["src/resources/*"],
        dest: "dist/templates/<%= pkg.path %>",
        flatten: true,
        expand: true
    },
    exportSite: {
        src: ["**"],
        cwd: 'src/resources/lar/',
        dest: "dist/lar/",
        expand: true
    }
};
};
```

I got the following error:

> ```
> Running "build" task
> (node:11400) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
>
> Running "copy" task
> > No "copy" targets found.
> Warning: Task "copy" failed. Use --force to continue.
> ```

Comment: Getting a similar issue did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the dependencies